# How can I concatenate elements from a lists into one variable in Python?

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

I'm currently trying to take the take the integer value of each letter in a word and have it be represented as one long continuous decimal value rather than added together or separated by new lines. The issue I'm having is that I'm unsure of how to take the elements out of the list.

```
def descAscii(words):
    dec = []
    for letters in words:
        dec.append(ord(letters))

    print dec
```

And when I call the function like so `descAscii("hello")` The following is printed: `[104, 101,108,108,111]`

My desired result would be 104101108108111

All input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.join` is the right way to build a string from a list. You can also skip your loop and any building of intermediate lists by using generator comprehension.

```
def descAscii(words):
    print ''.join(str(ord(letter)) for letter in words)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output as a string, then use

```
"".join(str(i) for i in dec)
```

If you want the output as an `int`, then use

```
In [83]: reduce(lambda a,b: a*1000 + b, dec)
Out[83]: 104101108108111
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def descAscii(words):
    dec = ""
    for letters in words:
        dec += str(ord(letters))

    print dec
```

You can just make a string and keep appending to it.

```
word = "hello"

>>> dec
'104101108108111'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you want the output as a string:

```
delimiter = '/'  
your_list = ['fee','fi','fo','fum']  
(delimiter).join(your_list)
```

[image: result]